# Keep (year) in a folder renaming

Tags: powershell, directory, rename

I got below powershell code , that moves and renames folders in to Tv-show folder and sub Season folder but I want it to keep the first parentese year part (2012):

an example:

EDIT 2: I have uploaded an folder example with and with out the year in it, and empty files with .mkv extensions.  The powershell script is also located where it is the idea that I normally would execute it.
Hope I do not break any rules by linking and using this gofile site. (havn't used it before).
Just extract it in C: or other location, but you have to change hardcoded destination variable if it other than C:

https://gofile.io/d/gSJw43

folder --> 
Arrow (2012) Season 8 S08 (1080p BluRay x265 HEVC 10bit AAC 5.1 Vyndros)\

containing files --> 
Arrow.S08E01.Starling.City.1080p.10bit.BluRay.AAC5.1.HEVC-Vyndros.mkv Arrow.S08E02.Welcome.to.Hong.Kong.1080p.10bit.BluRay.AAC5.1.HEVC-Vyndros.mkv Arrow.S08E03.Leap.of.Faith.1080p.10bit.BluRay.AAC5.1.HEVC-Vyndros.mkv Arrow.S08E04.Present.Tense.1080p.10bit.BluRay.AAC5.1.HEVC-Vyndros.mkv Arrow.S08E05.Prochnost.1080p.10bit.BluRay.AAC5.1.HEVC-Vyndros.mkv Arrow.S08E06.Reset.1080p.10bit.BluRay.AAC5.1.HEVC-Vyndros.mkv Arrow.S08E07.Purgatory.1080p.10bit.BluRay.AAC5.1.HEVC-Vyndros.mkv Arrow.S08E08.Crisis.on.Infinite.Earths.Part.Four.1080p.10bit.BluRay.AAC5.1.HEVC-Vyndros.mkv Arrow.S08E09.Green.Arrow.&.The.Canaries.1080p.10bit.BluRay.AAC5.1.HEVC-Vyndros.mkv Arrow.S08E10.Fadeout.1080p.10bit.BluRay.AAC5.1.HEVC-Vyndros.mkv

Creates folders and moves the files to the Season 08 folder:

Arrow\season 08\

But I want it to keep the year part in the Show folder:

Arrow (2012)\season 08\

Can the code be changed to do that ? (have to take into account that it's not always the (xxxx) part is in the original name, so the code has to look for: parentheses begin and for numbers and parentheses end = (xxxx)

The file names should not be changed

**Edit start for further explanation:**
I will run the powershell script per default, from the root of the folder, the script should examine for show folders. Please notice that there will be several different show folders, each containing maybe one or more season .mkv files:

example:

c:\test\powershell_script.ps1

c:\test\Arrow (2012) Season 8 S08 (1080p BluRay x265 HEVC 10bit AAC 5.1 Vyndros\Arrow.S08E01.Starling.City.1080p.10bit.BluRay.AAC5.1.HEVC-Vyndros.mkv
.

.

.

/

c:\test\Arrow (2012) Season 8 S08 (1080p BluRay x265 HEVC 10bit AAC 5.1 Vyndros\Arrow.S08E10.Starling.City.1080p.10bit.BluRay.AAC5.1.HEVC-Vyndros.mkv

c:\test\Altered Carbon (2018) Season 2 S02 (1080p DS4K NF WEBRip x265 HEVC 10bit DDP 5.1 Vyndros)\Altered.Carbon.S02E01.Phantom.Lady.1080p.10bit.NF.WEBRip.DDP5.1.HEVC-Vyndros.mkv
.

.

.

/

c:\test\Altered Carbon (2018) Season 2 S02 (1080p DS4K NF WEBRip x265 HEVC 10bit DDP 5.1 Vyndros)\Altered.Carbon.S02E08.Phantom.Lady.1080p.10bit.NF.WEBRip.DDP5.1.HEVC-Vyndros.mkv
.

.
.  several other show dirs with files

**Edit Finish**

```
###############
# make a folder for each different name before the SXX (season part) 
# and make a subfolder named Season XX for each SXX part that differs from each other.
# 
###############

# $Sourcefolder = 


# $DstBase = "c:\!foldertest\"  # Destination folder
$DstBase = Read-Host 'what is destination folder ?'   # Destination folder

Get-ChildItem -Include *.mkv,*.mp4,*.srt,*.avi,*.txt,*.nfo -Recurse -File|  # pick files with these extensions
  Where-Object BaseName -match "^(?<Series>.*?)\.?S(?<Season>\d{1,2})\.?E(?<Episode>\d{2})"|
    ForEach-Object {
      $Destination = "{0}\{1}\Season {2:00}\" -f $DstBase,$Matches.Series.replace('.',' ').Trim(),[int]$Matches.Season
      if (!(Test-Path $Destination)){MD $Destination -Force | Out-Null}
      "Moving file [{0}] to [{1}]" -f $_.FullName,$Destination # show information to user about files to Move 

      # popup window asking user for YES / NO confirmation
       $message  = 'User input'
       $question = 'Are you sure you want to proceed?'
       $choices  = '&Yes', '&No'

        $decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($message, $question, $choices, 1)
        if ($decision -eq 0) {
            Write-Host 'confirmed'
        } else {
            Write-Host 'cancelled'
        }
      # 
  Write-Host 'fortsat'

      $_ | Move-Item -Destination $Destination -Force    #move files to destination
    }

<# Sample tree after running the script:
> tree /F
└───series
    └───Breaking Bad
        ├───Season 01
        │       Breaking.Bad.S01E01.DVDRip.XviD-ORPHEUS.avi
        │       Breaking.Bad.S01E01.DVDRip.XviD-ORPHEUS.spa.srt
        │
        ├───Season 04
        │       Breaking.Bad.S04E01.Box.Cutter.720p.hdtv.x264-orenji.mkv
        │       Breaking.Bad.S04E01.Box.Cutter.720p.hdtv.x264-orenji.spa.srt
        │
        └───Season 05
                Breaking.Bad.S05E15.720p.HDTV.x264-EVOLVE.mkv
                Breaking.Bad.S05E15.720p.HDTV.x264-EVOLVE.spa.srt
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case it would be best to determine the output path **before** entering the loop:

```
$DstBase = 'D:\Test\Arrow (2012) Season 8 S08 (1080p BluRay x265 HEVC 10bit AAC 5.1 Vyndros)'

# get the source folder as DirectoryInfo object
$dstItem = Get-Item -Path $DstBase
# extract the year, season and series from the source folder name
$year    = ([regex]'(\(\d{4}\))').Match($dstItem.Name).Groups[1].Value
$season  = ([regex]'Season\s+(\d+)').Match($dstItem.Name).Groups[1].Value

# test if the folder name had a (year) part of not
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($year)) {
    $series = ($dstItem.Name -split 'Season')[0].Trim()
    $folder = '{0}\Season {1:00}' -f $series, [int]$season
}
else {
    $series = ($dstItem.Name -split 'Season')[0].Replace($year, '').Trim()
    $folder = '{0} {1}\Season {2:00}' -f $series, $year, [int]$season
}
# and combine that to become a full target path
$Destination = Join-Path -Path $dstItem.Parent.FullName -ChildPath $folder

# create the folder if it does not exist
if (!(Test-Path -Path $Destination -PathType Container)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path $Destination -ItemType Directory
}
```

Then do your loop:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $DstBase -Include *.mkv,*.mp4,*.srt,*.avi,*.txt,*.nfo -Recurse -File |  # pick files with these extensions
  Where-Object BaseName -match "^(?<Series>.*?)\.?S(?<Season>\d{1,2})\.?E(?<Episode>\d{2})" |
    ForEach-Object {
      "Moving file [{0}] to [{1}]" -f $_.FullName, $Destination # show information to user about files to Move 

      # do your confirmation popups if you must

      # move the file
      $_ | Move-Item -Destination $Destination -Force    #move files to destination
    }
```

Comment: I get following error runnig first part:

`PS C:\!foldertest> C:\!foldertest\Make_subfolders_from_SXX_part_of_filename_KEEP_YEAR.ps1
Exception calling "Replace" with "2" argument(s): "String cannot be of zero length.
Parameter name: oldValue"
At C:\!foldertest\Make_subfolders_from_SXX_part_of_filename_KEEP_YEAR.ps1:8 char:1
+ $series  = ($dstItem.Name -split 'Season')[0].Replace($year, '').Trim ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException`

Comment: @muggi That would mean variable `$year`, which should be something like `(2012)` is empty. Probably, you are using a folder name either **without** a (year) part or where the year is not 4 digits long, while all your examples do have that. If in real life, this is not the case then give **real** examples so we know what to work with. Your question literally says: _But I want it to keep the year part in the Show folder__

Comment: I actually wrote "(have to take into account that it's not allways the (xxxx) part is in the original name, so the code has to look for: parentheses begin and for numbers and parentheses end = (xxxx)"

But yes, I should have explained it more clearly that the year part not always is in the foldername, and given an more detailed data sample, sorry

Comment: @muggi Sorry, I missed that. I have updated the code to check for a year part.

Comment: thank you for the update :-)
It seems like it only creates and Season 00 folder and do not move any .mkv files.
I tried running the 2 part code you gave, both each and also  both codes in once instance. (do not know if makes any difference to how the code behave).

I added a link in my original post with a small zipped file, containing folder and filename example. Also the powershell code is in the zip, so one could se where i plan to run it from.